# Unittest - Mocking object and return values of methods via @patch

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a problem mocking the return value of an object's methods using the `patch` decorator of `unittest.mock` in Python. A minimal example is this:

dummy_objects.py:

```
class DummyObject:
    def foo(self, int):
        return f"foo-{int}-"
    def bar(self, int):
        return f"bar-{int}-"
```

test_dummy.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import dummy_objects as do

dummy_patch = Mock(spec=do.DummyObject)
dummy_patch.foo.return_value = "9999"

@patch("dummy_objects.DummyObject", new=dummy_patch)
class TestCaseOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_patching_foo(self):
        tmp = do.DummyObject()
        self.assertEqual(tmp.foo(), "9999")
```

I would expect that `tmp.foo()` returns "9999" due to the patch-decorator. However, I get a new MagicMock as the output shows:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

FAILED (failures=1)


9999 != <Mock name='mock().foo()' id='2087245816552'>

Expected :<Mock name='mock().foo()' id='2087245816552'>
Actual   :9999
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You miss a `return_value`. You need `dummy_patch.return_value.foo.return_value = "9999"` for this to work, because you need to patch the instance, not the class. Apart from that, this example does not really make sense, because you test the same object that you have patched - but maybe this was for illustration only.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this really saved me after two days of desperation!
If you want I can accept this as an answer.

And yes - the example was just a minimal example for illustration.

Comment: Glad I could help! I think I won't write an answer, as this has been answered before (I certainly answered similar questions...), and will be closed as a duplicate at some point anyway.